# How to pop a modal stack and navigate from the same function

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

I'm working a personal app for myself and I'm making use of the `Prism` library and the `NavigationService` that it implements.

I have a function called `NavigateToFlowAsync()` that is defined as follows:

```cs
public async Task NavigateToFlowAsync(){
   await NavigationService.GoBackAsync(true);
   await NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(NavigationPage)}/{nameof(NewPage)}");
}
```

This function will be called from a page that is part of the modal stack that is being popped with the `GoBackAsync(true)` call made in `NavigateToFlow()`.
The behavior I'm getting at the moment is that the current page is popped, but the subsequent navigation does not occur.
I've tried debugging and looking at the resulting `INavigationResult` that is returned from both of these navigation calls, but in both cases the result is successful.

For example, if my navigation stack looks like this:

`NavigationPage (which has been navigated to modally) -> PageOne -> PageTwo -> PageThree`

And PageThree contains the `NavigateToFlowAsync()` function, I would expect the resulting NavigationStack to look like:
`NavigationPage (which has been navigated to modally) -> NewPage`

**However** what it *actually* looks like is:

`NavigationPage (which has been navigated to modally) -> PageOne -> PageTwo`

The best theory I have at the moment is the `NavigateAsync` call doesn't work because at that point the ViewModel that is making the call corresponds to a page that is no longer in the stack.
Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided that it would make sense to ask the very people that created Prism about this issue, cause if anyone's gonna have an answer it will be them!
Brian Lagunas has said "*You can't navigate from a page you just removed from the navigation stack.*"
So there we go, unfortunately what I was after just can't happen. I'll find another way to get around it!

Answer (score 2):

Try *queueing* the actions, so that they are independent of the original page:

```cs
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
    await NavigationService.GoBackAsync(true);
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(NavigationPage)}/{nameof(NewPage)}");
});
```

Note: I have deliberately NOT done `await Device.BeginInvoke...`. The goal is to take those two lines, and queue a task to MainThread that will run them after the containing method returns.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Thought for sure it would! When using your suggestion, the behavior still seems that the modal is correctly popped but the ```await NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(NavigationPage)}/{nameof(NewPage)}");```  is completely ignored, although does still return a successful navigation result. 
Here's a screenshot of the debug session showing the NavigationResults: https://imgur.com/a/pYirxDF

Comment: What happens if add `await Task.Delay(1000);` between the two lines? (If that works, then try shorter time.)

Comment: Same behaviour, apparently. I tried delays of 50, 1000, and 2000. All of them didn't seem to do anything (expect for delaying of course). Not sure how much use this is, but I used ```Debug.Writeline(NavigationService.GetCurrentUriPath());``` in the ```OnAppearing``` method of the page we end up on after popping. The stack only shows that page (in this case ```MainPage```).

Comment: Sorry, I meant ```GetNavigationUriPath()```, not ```GetCurrentUriPath()```